# Unable to start the VSCode debugger with the Gauge Framework

Tags: vscode-debugger, getgauge

Software Versions:

- Python: 3.9.7
- Gauge: 1.4.1
- Visual Studio Code: 1.60.0
- Gauge plugin for VSCode (getgauge.gauge): v0.0.21
- Pylance (ms-python.vscode-pylance): v2021.9.0

I have a Gauge framework based on Python setup. I have a spec file, with scenarios installed. I also have a break point set at point in the glue code. When I click on the Debug Spec hyperlink, I get an error message that says the following:

Failed to start debugger: The debugger does not work for a stand alone file. Please open the folder c:\Projects\IAS_Desktop_Automation\ias_desktop_automation.

[Error GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOkR3.gif)

Please advise how I could get the debugger to work.

Update: I've got log file results too as well from gauge.log

```
09-09-2021 11:06:34.700 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Created gauge_screenshots_dir at c:\Projects\GaugeFramework\ias_net_automation\reports\html-report\screenshots
09-09-2021 11:06:34.701 [Gauge] [INFO] Compatible version of plugin python not found. Installing plugin python...
09-09-2021 11:06:34.701 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Gathering metadata for python
09-09-2021 11:06:34.703 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/python?l=python&p=html-report,python,screenshot,xml-report&o=windows&a=amd64
09-09-2021 11:06:35.105 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Plugin python 0.3.17 is already installed.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.106 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Plugin html-report is already installed.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.107 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Plugin screenshot is already installed.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.107 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Parsing started.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.107 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Started concepts parsing.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.144 [Gauge] [DEBUG] 38 concepts parsing completed.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.144 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Started specifications parsing.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.144 [Gauge] [DEBUG] 1 specifications parsing completed.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.144 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Parsing completed.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.504 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Checking updates...
09-09-2021 11:06:35.505 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/html-report?l=python&p=html-report,python,screenshot,xml-report&o=windows&a=amd64
09-09-2021 11:06:35.675 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/python?l=python&p=html-report,python,screenshot,xml-report&o=windows&a=amd64
09-09-2021 11:06:35.696 [python] [INFO] Python: 3.9.7
09-09-2021 11:06:35.696 [python] [DEBUG] Loading step implementations from c:\Projects\GaugeFramework\ias_net_automation\step_impl dirs.
09-09-2021 11:06:35.771 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/screenshot?l=python&p=html-report,python,screenshot,xml-report&o=windows&a=amd64
09-09-2021 11:06:35.978 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/xml-report?l=python&p=html-report,python,screenshot,xml-report&o=windows&a=amd64
09-09-2021 11:06:41.804 [python] [INFO] Runner Ready for Debugging
```

Here's one from lsp.log with maybe some more revealing information:

```
09-09-2021 11:07:16.033 [Gauge] [DEBUG] jsonrpc2: --> request #7: textDocument/codeLens: {"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%!!(MISSING)A(MISSING)/Projects/GaugeFramework/ias_net_automation/specs/testData.spec"}}
09-09-2021 11:07:16.033 [Gauge] [DEBUG] jsonrpc2: <-- result #7: textDocument/codeLens: [{"range":{"start":{"line":2,"character":0},"end":{"line":2,"character":12}},"command":{"title":"Run Scenario","command":"gauge.execute","arguments":["c:\\Projects\\GaugeFramework\\ias_net_automation\\specs\\testData.spec:3"]}},{"range":{"start":{"line":2,"character":0},"end":{"line":2,"character":14}},"command":{"title":"Debug Scenario","command":"gauge.debug","arguments":["c:\\Projects\\GaugeFramework\\ias_net_automation\\specs\\testData.spec:3"]}},{"range":{"start":{"line":0,"character":0},"end":{"line":0,"character":8}},"command":{"title":"Run Spec","command":"gauge.execute","arguments":["c:\\Projects\\GaugeFramework\\ias_net_automation\\specs\\testData.spec"]}},{"range":{"start":{"line":0,"character":0},"end":{"line":0,"character":10}},"command":{"title":"Debug Spec","command":"gauge.debug","arguments":["c:\\Projects\\GaugeFramework\\ias_net_automation\\specs\\testData.spec"]}}]
```

Comment: I've also got log files to show what's happening as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was introduced by the latest gauge extension update (version 0.0.21)

1. Change your Auto Update Extensions to None
2. Down rev your gauge extension in vscode to 0.0.20

You can get version 20 from here under the Version History tab:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=getgauge.gauge#install-from-source

Place the download in your workspace than run the following command in the terminal:

```
code --install-extension getgauge.gauge-0.0.20.vsix
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately did not work for me.  Tested on both MacOS and Windows 10.  My error message shows "Failed to create test explorer" instead and the code hints (run/debug hyper links) do not render at all.  No IntelliSense either.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the Gauge plugin for VSCode to v0.0.20 and the debugger worked as expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfvIo.png)

There is an issue raised in github to look at the issue in the latest version: https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-vscode/issues/726